# React Native DropDownPicker not setting default value (react-native-dropdown-picker)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I am trying to set the default value to a dropdown component using react-native-dropdown-picker.

I get the value from the database when the screen loads and assign that value to the "value property" of the Dropdown component, however the value is not selected in the Dropdown.

If I hardcode the value property in the dropdown it works, it's just when I assign the value from the database that doesn't work. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here.

This is what I'm trying to do.

This is the definition of the component.

```
    import DropDownPicker, {
      ItemType,
      ValueType,
    } from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

const DropDown = ({
  name,
  style,
  onChangeValue,
  value = null,

  ...props
}: DropDownProps) => {
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState<ValueType | null>(value);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      {name && <MaterialIcons name={name} color={colors.gray} size={24} />}
      <DropDownPicker
        {...props}
        setValue={setNewValue}
        placeholderStyle={styles.label}
        labelStyle={styles.label}
        style={styles.dropdown}
        value={newValue}
        containerStyle={styles.dropdownContainer}
        listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
        onChangeValue={changedVal => {
          if (changedVal && onChangeValue) {
            // @ts-ignore:next-line
            onChangeValue(changedVal);
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Here's how I use the component.**

```
<DropDown
  open={open}
  value={selectedCategory}
  items={CATEGORIES}
  name="list"
  placeholder={t('Category')}
  onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
  style={[styles.input, styles.dropdownIndex]}
  onChangeValue={handleChange('category')}
/>

<DropDown
  open={stateOpen}
  value={selectedState}
  items={STATES}
  name="location-pin"
  placeholder={t('State')}
  onOpen={() => setStateOpen(true)}
  onClose={() => setStateOpen(false)}
  style={styles.input}
  onChangeValue={handleChange('state')}
/>
```

**Here I create my state variable to store the value coming from the database.**

```
const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState('AL');
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('animal-protection');
```

**Here I assign the value to the state variables and that's when the value it's supposed to change in the dropdown, but it doesn't happen.**

```
setInitialValues({
  ...initialValues,
  foundationName: foundation?.name || '',
  description: foundation?.description || '',
  phone: foundation?.phone || '',
  regionServed: foundation?.regionServed || '',
  headquarters: foundation?.headquarters || '',
  city: foundation?.address?.city || '',
  zipcode: foundation?.address?.zipcode?.toString(),
});

setSelectedCategory(foundation?.category[0]);
setSelectedState(foundation?.address?.state);
```

**When I log the state variables in the console the values are there, but again the value does not change in the dropdown.**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedCategory);
    console.log(selectedState);
  }, [selectedCategory, selectedState]);
```